# Complex analysis : If $z =re^{i\theta}$, then prove that $|e^{iz}| =e^{-r\sin\theta}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Problem :

If $z =re^{i\theta}$, then prove that $|e^{iz} | =e^{-r\sin\theta}$

My working :

$z = re^{i\theta} = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$

$\Rightarrow iz = ir(\cos\theta +\sin\theta) $ = $-r\sin\theta +ir\cos\theta $

$\Rightarrow e^{iz} =e^{(-r\sin\theta +ir\cos\theta)} = e^{-\sin\theta} e^{ir\cos\theta} $

$\Rightarrow |e^{iz}| = |e^{-r\sin\theta}||e^{ri\cos\theta}|$

Now please guide how to proceed further to get the result... thanks.

Comment: $|e^{i\theta}|=1$. You seem to have mis-stated the problem.

Comment: In the title of your problem, instead of $|e^{i\theta}|$ you meant $|e^{iz}|$, didn't you?

Comment: If the title of your problem is as @bof said, then you already proved it, $|e^{ricos(\theta)}|=1$ and $|e^{-rsin(\theta)}| = e^{-rsin(\theta)}$

Answer (score 7):

You're almost there, Now just use the fact that $|e^{ix}|=1$ for all real $x$, and that $e^a>0$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $|e^{a+ib}|=e^a$ assuming $a,b$ real; i.e., $|e^z|=e^{\Re(z)}$.

Since $iz=ire^{i\theta}=-r\sin\theta+ir\cos\theta$, $|e^{iz}|=e^{\Re(iz)}=e^{-r\sin\theta}$.